# Select a grouped table (by Id) filtered by a datetime column according to NULL and MAX(date) values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that I have a table with pretty many columns in there, but that has to be returned filtered just by Id and EndDate.

| Id | EndDate | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |  |
| 1 | 01.01.2022 15:25 |  |
| 1 | 01.01.2022 15.24 |  |
| 2 | 15.01.2022 10:00 |  |
| 2 | 15.01.2022 11:00 |  |
| 2 | 17.01.2022 00:00 |  |
| 3 | NULL |  |
| 3 | 10.10.2022 22:12 |  |
| 4 | 18.05.2022 17:15 |  |
| 4 | 18.05.2022 17:17 |  |
| 4 | 19.05.2022 00:00 |  |

The resulting table must be the following:

| Id | EndDate | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |  |
| 2 | 17.01.2022 00:00 |  |
| 3 | NULL |  |
| 4 | 19.05.2022 00:00 |  |

The record with a specific Id must be picked either having a NULL EndDate value or MAX value otherwise. As it's seen on the resulting table, record with Id = 1 has NULL EndDate so then it must be picked, record with Id = 4 doesn't have a NULLable EndDate, so the value with MAX(EndDate) must be returned.

I was trying different scenarios with joining and UNIONing, but it seems desperate. Also, I considered something with CTE tables, but it seems irrelevant. The point is also get an optimal solution, because resulting table are considered to be joined to another table.
If there will be at least an idea of how to get a desired result, I would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER in a common table expression to define the priority.  Just replace the NULL with a date far in the future like 9999-12-31, then you can just order the date.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ISNULL(EndDate,'99991231') DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.myTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.RN = 1;
```

Comment: Wow, fairly simply. Seems like what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With simple aggregation and a `CASE` expression where you check if there are any `null` dates for each `Id`:

```
SELECT Id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(EndDate) THEN MAX(EndDate) END AS EndDate
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Id;
```

The condition `COUNT(*) = COUNT(EndDate)` is satisfied only if all dates are not `null`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/57WUUp3v).

Comment: That's a good one answer as well, but the nuance is in grouping. I have a little more columns to fetch from table. With some of them (f.g. dates) will be pretty hard to deal, but I got the point. Thanks